# how to join in Linq dan display like tree in gridview

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

**class**

```
public class category {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string c_name { get; set; }
}
public class item {
    int id { get; set; }
    string item_name { get; set; }
    int category_id { get; set; }
}
```

**record**

```
 // |  id   |   c_name    |        |  id  | item_name  | category_id |
 // |   1   |   fruit     |        |   1  | apple      |      1      |
 // |   2   |   electronic|        |   2  | banana     |      1      |
 //                                |   3  | rice cooker|      2      |
```

how to join with `Linq` in list and display in grid like tree ?

```
var c = new List<category>();
var i = new List<item>();
```

Comment: What do you try until now?

Comment: display with 
    //gridControl1.DataSource

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables like:

```
var q = from ci in c
    join ii in i on ci.id equals ii.id
    select new { category = ci, item = ii};
```